# Remove value from firebase dictionary with swift, filter on client side blocked users

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure is like this;

```
 "blockByUser" : {
  "pcAkkvLY1TYseqk04sISUqop3Wt1" : {
    "7OYw2AtvZ7hxprFiX2e1LOn1DWs2" : true,
    "W4uaW1pOtkYUMh1jTJJVXQu0u6f1" : true
  }
 }

"users" : {
   "Gn0SwQOmUvNkAFeg0YpGax75cpz2" : {
     "blocked" : {
       "pcAkkvLY1TYseqk04sISUqop3Wt1" : true
     },
     "capacity" : "NO",
     "country" : "Netherlands",
     "email" : "katnl"
   },
   "iDlNUNNAsiN0JmO8bEdYAdANcn62" : {
     "blocked" : {
       "Gn0SwQOmUvNkAFeg0YpGax75cpz2" : true
     },
     "capacity" : "NO",
     "country" : "Netherlands",
     "email" : "dal"
   },
   "pcAkkvLY1TYseqk04sISUqop3Wt1" : {
     "capacity" : "NO",
     "country" : "Netherlands",
     "email" : "test",
   }
 }
```

I'm now I have to filter on the client side, remove the keys from blockedByUser so I have 2 dictionaries one the 'complete' list of users and one blockedByUsers, now I run into problems to update my collectionView, because the firebase data is async and I'm not sure how to make this working like this:

```
func fetchBlockedUsers() {

        print("Fetching blocked users..")

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("blockedByUser").child(currentUserUID)
        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            self.users.removeAll()

            let blocked = dictionaries

            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                var dict = dictionaries
                for block in blocked {
                    dict.removeValue(forKey: block.key)
                }


                dict.forEach({ (key, value) in
                    guard let userDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                    let user = UserModel(uid: key, dictionary: userDictionary)
                    self.users.append(user)
                })

                self.collectionView?.reloadData()

            }) { (err) in
                print("Failed to fetch users for search:", err)
            }

        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch users for search:", err)
        }

    }
```

But maybe it's better to fan-out the data and use firebase functions to manage the data?

Comment: This is very difficult to understand. Can you please clarify the question and what you are trying to do?

Comment: A user has the ability to block an other user in the app, so Apple wants that the user thats being blocked is also not showing up in the user list anymore for that user.

Comment: @Jay trying to find a good solution to block users for a user and how to store this in and with Firebase, is it better for duplicate every user for every new user in the app and if the block that user remove that user from the users list for that user? Or do it on the client side?

Comment: Is the goal here to display a list of users; blocked ones are not displayed and the user that is blocked knows which users blocked them? ie. there would be three lists. 1) Users 2) blocked users 3) users who blocked this user?

Comment: @Jay I've a list users with all the user that are in the system, now a user has the ability to block a user and then that user can't see that blocked user not anymore in the users list. Thats the main question. Then the user also have a list of blocked users, but thats not that hard ;-) 

Is the solution to fan out the complete users list to each user? Or having a list with blocked users for that user and then on the client side filtering them out of the list of users?

Comment: I think you have the simplest solution. Within each user node, keep a list of users that user has blocked. When the user logs into the app, read that list first (so the app will know the blocked users) and as the app iterates over the existing users to load them in (via .childAdded) if the user being loaded matches a user in the blocked user list, don't add them to the array of users. You could also do it via .value as in your code.